# Installing VBox in Ubuntu 18.04 with secure booth enabled in dual boot machine

Tags: dual-boot, virtualbox, uefi, secure-boot

Sorry if this is obvious but I'm a beginner and don't want to mess it up! So I have a machine with dual boot Ubuntu 18.04/Windows 10 and secure boot enabled. The secure boot is not optional so disabling it is not a solution. I'm trying to install vbox but it asks for MOK enroll. Now I'm not sure if this would 'break' the dual boot (or anything else for that matter). BTW I have sudo privileges, but not the actual admin so I also don't know if this would affect anything(?

Comment: Enrolling MOK won't break anything.

Comment: @Pilot6 it won't alter any other password or anything?

Answer (score 1):

Enrolling the MOK shouldn't break secure boot. You'll just have to reboot, enter the one-time password you've defined and you're good to go. Secure Boot stays enabled.

Comment: It's not secure boot I'm worried about, it's the dual boot. I was told it "may" break it. But a "may" won't do it for me.

Comment: I don't see why it would interfere with the bootloader.